# Create a JPA Criteria fully dynamically

Tags: java, generics, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Usually I'm a Hibernate user and for my new project we use JPA 2.0.

My DAO receives a Container with a generic.

```
public class Container<T> {
  private String fieldId;    // example "id"
  private T value;           // example new Long(100) T is a Long
  private String operation;  // example ">"

  // getter/setter
}
```

The following lines won't compile:

```
if (">".equals(container.getOperation()) {
  criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.get(container.getFieldId()), container.getValue());
}
```

Because I must specify the type like this:

```
if (">".equals(container.getOperation()) {
  criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.<Long>get(container.getFieldId()), (Long)container.getValue());
}
```

But I don't want to do that! Because I use a generic in my container!
Have you an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as your `T` is `Comparable` (it's required for `greaterThan`), you should be able to do something like the following:

```
public class Container<T extends Comparable<T>> { 
    ...
    public <R> Predicate toPredicate(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<R> root) {
        ...
        if (">".equals(operation) {
            return cb.greaterThan(root.<T>get(fieldId), value);
        } 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You saved me in 2023