# Jpa Specifications predicate for greaterThan and lesserThan conditions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, specifications

i'm using spring data jpa specifiations for dynamic complex queries...

In my service layer, i create the specification like this,

```
SearchSpecification<User> spec = new CommonSpecification<Case>(new SearchCriteria("client.id", ">", 6));


@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    Predicate predicate = null;
    switch (searchCriteria.getOperator()) {
        case ">" :

        Path<?> p = getPath(Integer.class, root, searchCriteria.getKey());
        Expression<? extends Object> ex = getExpression(gtClazz, root, searchCriteria.getKey());

        predicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(ex, searchCriteria.getValue());
     break;
    }
    return predicate;
}

private <T, Object> Path<Object> getPath(Class<Object> clazz, Root<T> root, String key) {
    String[] fields = key.split("\\.");
    Path<?> path = root;
    for (String field : fields) {
        path = (Path<Object>) path.get(field);
    }
    return (Path<Object>) path;
}

private <T, R> Expression<R> getExpression(Class<R> clazz, Root<T> root, String key) {
    Path<Object> path = (Path<Object>) getPath(clazz, root, key);
    Expression<Class<?>> expression = path.type();
    return (Expression<R>) expression;
}
```

I'm getting issues on this below line,

```
predicate = criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(ex, searchCriteria.getValue());
```

how can i use the greaterThan/LesserThan conditions using JPA Specifications.

Thanks in advance.

Vishnu.

Comment: what is the exception that you are getting. Also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296870/create-a-jpa-criteria-fully-dynamically

Comment: for *Numbers* you have to use `CriteriaBuilder.gt()`

Comment: I'm getting the exception like given "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [client.id] on this ManagedType [com.visnu.entity.User]"

Comment: Issue Fixed... Thanks